# Ionic v3 does not load all data on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, loaddata

I've a ion-list (a tabs) with items on a page, like this:

```
<ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'valid'">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let review of reviews_delay; let i = index">
         <ion-item class="review review-delay" (click)="showValid(i)" text-wrap>
         </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
</ion-list>
```

This is my scss class:

```
.review { 
    &.review-delay { 
        border-left: 7px solid map-get($colors, red) !important; 
        border-color: rgba(200, 61, 40, 0.4); 
    } 
}
```

On android all data is displayed but on iOS only the first line:

[image]

I've put the load data in ngOnInit, maybe is the wrong place?

Thanks for helping

Comment: What does your scss file look like for this page? how is your 'review review-delay' class typed in the file?

Comment: Hi, this is my scss class: `.review {
    &.review-delay {
        border-left: 7px solid map-get($colors, red) !important;
        border-color: rgba(200, 61, 40, 0.4);
    }
}`

Comment: Can you add that to your question to make it a little easier to read?

Comment: It's done, i've update the question